# Configuring SSL on Tomcat/Spring Boot ("Could not find key store classpath:keystore.jks" error)

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, https, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure SSL. Hovever, I get an exception saying

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Could not find key store classpath:keystore.jks
```

This is my application-https.properties file:

```
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
server.ssl.key-password = another-secret
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?currentSchema=myschema
spring.datasource.username=postgresql
spring.datasource.password=postgresql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=https
```

I've read documentation about ssl and I don't know what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have in your classpath the keystore.jks  file?

Comment: No. Doesn't Spring Boot add that file?

Comment: No, try to read this: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

Comment: Do I need to have a certificate in a client application to have an access to the server application (which is the subject of the question)?

Comment: I know you fixed this already, but this looks like a duplicate of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858217/spring-boot-executable-war-keystore-not-found

if your keystore file was inside your jar, tomcat could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did the following:

1. placed the .jks file inside main/resources.
2. you ran the command:    mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is not readable from classpath other than Spring. (In case of kafka we don't have any option and kafka always expect location to be on filesystem not in jar file.) So I suggest to  use below property and give absolute path to keystore location.

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:certificate.jks
```

In code:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location}")
    private Resource keystoreLocation;

props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keystoreLocation.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

This way you can read the keystore. You may need to copy the file on file system rather than in Jar.