# spring-boot executable war keystore not found

Tags: tomcat, ssl, spring-boot, war, keystore

I build spring-boot executable war with ssl support.
My application.properties file is:

```
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
server.ssl.key-password = another-secret
```

WAR file contains 'keystore.jks' file. But I get strange exception:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Could not find key store classpath:keystore.jks
```

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/D:/projects/vi3na/vi3na.web/target/vi3na.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/keystore.jks
```

What does sign '!' mean in the path 'D:/projects/vi3na/vi3na.web/target/vi3na.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/keystore.jks'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** As a result of [this enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56777), the limitation described below no longer applies. Tomcat 8.0.28+ and 7.0.66+ can load a key store from within a jar file.

#### Original answer

I guess that you're using Tomcat as the embedded servlet container? As [noted in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl), Tomcat does not currently support loading a keystore or trust store from within a jar:

> Tomcat requires the key store (and trust store if you’re using one) to be directly accessible on the filesystem, i.e. it cannot be read from within a jar file.

You should move `keystore.jks` out of your jar and update `server.ssl.key-store` with its location on the file system.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I'm using embedded Tomcat. I need JSP engine inside. And I  am using my keystore.jks on the file system. Good answer!

Comment: Hi Andy, please can you point me to the documentation where Tomcat should not be able to read keystore from a jar, I can't find it? I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and Embedded Tomcat 8.0.24 and everything works like a charme; if I try to upgrade Spring Boot to version 1.2.7 or 1.3.0 (same embedded Tomcat) I get the same error of Igor. So it depends on Spring Boot and not on Tomcat maybe?

Comment: @lincetto I'm not sure that the Tomcat limitation is documented anywhere, but [here's the enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56777) that added support for loading key stores from within a JAR.

Comment: The issue has been fixed and classpath for keystore file works now. I am using Spring boot `2.2.5.RELEASE`.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson - I am using tomcat.version 8.5.27 & spring-boot-starter-tomcat 1.5.10.RELEASE - my keystore file present in jar and not able to read.

Comment: This error still shows in Spring Boot `Could not find key store: 'null'`

Answer (score 4):

In my Spring Boot application I resolved this issue by placing `.jks` file into resource folder.

[image]

Comment: I did the same. but when I run it as  a jar , it's causing file not found exception. Any idea?

Comment: That wont do anything

Answer (score 1):

My bad was, by adding `server.ssl.enabled=true` without giving spring boot any details. so I just remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following steps to generate a Java KeyStore (JKS) and configure it in application.properties of your application:

1- Generate JKS

```
jmendoza@jmendoza:~$ keytool -genkey -alias selfsigned_localhost_sslserver -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 700 -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore ssl-server.jks
```

2- Config JKS in application.properties

```
server.port=8081
server.ssl.key-alias=electoralsystem-store
server.ssl.key-password=jmendoza
server.ssl.key-store=/home/jmendoza/IdeaProjects/dummy/config/electoralsystem-store.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

3- Invoke service from postman

https://localhost:8081/api/process

Note: For postman remember, Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
                            Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is not readable from classpath other than Spring. (In case of kafka we don't have any option and kafka always expect location to be on filesystem not in jar file.) So I suggest to  use below property and give absolute path to keystore location.

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:certificate.jks
```

In code:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location}")
    private Resource keystoreLocation;

props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keystoreLocation.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

This way you can read the keystore. You may need to copy the file on file system rather than in Jar.