# Spring boot embedded tomcat not loading SSL keystore file from classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I am using Spring boot 1.2.7 for my application and as a requirement I have to load the SSL cert from classpath. So, I added my PKCS12 file in my classpath and used following code (in `AppInitializer` class to load it:

```
final String sslKeystoreFilepath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(sslKeystoreFilename).getFile();
```

I am noticing two things here:

1. The string contains `file:` in it. If I run the same code through a plain standalone program with `main` method, I couldn't see anything like `file:`.
2. When I run the Spring boot app (using generated fat jar), it throws exception saying:

`SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type PKCS12 with path /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/build/libs/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev.jar!/dev_keystore.p12 due to /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/build/libs/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev.jar!/dev_keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/my_user/Projects/my_app/build/libs/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev.jar!/dev_keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how so you add your file to the class path?

Comment: Drop the file in `src/main/resources` and that gets bundled in the JAR file. Am I doing anything wrong here? Please suggest if there is another way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add this configuration in your .properties file as belows, rather than getting the string,

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:dev_keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

If you need to do what you are doing now, let me know, I will give that answer

Comment: I cannot do this for a design consideration in our app.

Answer (score 2):

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32902333/1798842) seems that Tomcat can't read the keystore conatined in a jar, but I'm not sure of that because I use Spring Boot 1.2.5 and everything works like a charme with the keystore in the classpath.
However I've exactly the same error of yours when I try to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.2.7 and above, so I concluded that depends on Spring Boot.
At this time, I downgraded to 1.2.5 version. :(

Comment: This sounds interesting. Because mine is a new application and I started using Spring Boot 1.2.6 to begin with. If it works in 1.2.5 and not the latest, I think you should create an issue ticket in their JIRA, no?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would help someone, but on Spring 1.5.8, if you have placed your key into your project root level, just add this into your application.yml :

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: some_password
    key-alias: tomcat
```

and it will work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me running from a JAR with Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE.

```
@Bean public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
    ...
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createSslConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();

    connector.setScheme("https");
    connector.setSecure(true);
    connector.setPort(8443);

    protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
    protocol.setKeystoreType("pkcs12");
    protocol.setKeystorePass("changeit");
    protocol.setKeyAlias("tomcat");

    try {
        ClassPathResource keystoreResource = new ClassPathResource("keystore");
        URL keystoreUrl = keystoreResource.getURL();
        String keystoreLocation = keystoreUrl.toString();
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystoreLocation);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [keystore]", ex);
    }

    return connector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is not readable from classpath other than Spring. (In case of kafka we don't have any option and kafka always expect location to be on filesystem not in jar file.) So I suggest to  use below property and give absolute path to keystore location.

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:certificate.jks
```

In code:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location}")
    private Resource keystoreLocation;

props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keystoreLocation.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

This way you can read the keystore. You may need to copy the file on file system rather than in Jar.